# How to handle losing Internet connection with NSURLSession?

Tags: ios, swift, nsurlsession

I am using NSURL to scrape HTML from a website. Problem is, if the internet cuts out during the NSURL request, the app crashes.
Code:

```
let myUrl = NSURL(string: "http://www.mywebsite.com/page.html")
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: myUrl!)
request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
    data, response, error in
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0)) {
        let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        if error != nil {
             print("Error: \(error)")
        } 
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            self.testLabel.text = "\(responseString!)"
        }
    }
}
task.resume()
```

I can check for internet connection before the NSURL connection with this code, however there is still the possibility of the internet cutting out during the operation:
Code with internet connection check before NSURL:

```
let myUrl = NSURL(string: "http://www.mywebsite.com/page.html")
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: myUrl!)
request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
    data, response, error in
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0)) {
        let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        if error != nil {
             print("Error: \(error)")
        } 
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            self.testLabel.text = "\(responseString!)"
        }
    }
}
task.resume()
```

To combat this problem I have researched using a try/catch operation, however I have had not luck successfully construction one that doesnt give me an error. Is there a way to wrap the whole NSURL operation in a giant try/catch that catches any errors? I was thinking something along the lines of this, but it does not work:
Code:

```
let myUrl = NSURL(string: "http://www.mywebsite.com/page.html")
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: myUrl!)
request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
        data, response, error in
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0)) {
    let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    if error != nil {
         print("Error: \(error)")
    } 
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        self.testLabel.text = "\(responseString!)"
    }
  }
}
task.resume()
} catch {
    timer.invalidate
    sendAlert("Error", message: "You are not connected to the internet")
}
```

Comment: Looks like you want something like [Reachability](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html)

Comment: Just unwrap data using guard let data = data where error == nil else { return }

Comment: You are doing forced unwrapping of `data` (e.g. `data!`) before you check for errors. Never do forced unwrapping unless you know, for a fact, that it can never be `nil`. Otherwise you will crash. So, as Leo suggested, add some error handling that ensures that `data` was not `nil` and that `error` was `nil`.

Answer (score 5):

The proper way to pronounce `!` is "I swear on my program's life." Because that's what you're doing. Why do you feel you have to use `!`? Use `guard-let` to work everything out for you:

```
    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
        data, response, error in

        guard error == nil else {
            print("Error: \(error)")
            return
        }

        guard let data = data else {
            fatalError("error was nil, but no data. This should never happen")
        }

        guard let responseString = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) else {
            print("Couldn't decode data")
            return
        }

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            self.testLabel.text = "\(responseString)"
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should only force unwrap a variable if you know for a 100% there is a value there, otherwise you will cause your app to crash. If you require more information on this you should review the Optional Chaining section of the [The Swift Programming Language guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/OptionalChaining.html)

For checking for a

The code below should work for you.

```
    let myUrl = NSURL(string: "http://www.mywebsite.com/page.html")
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: myUrl!)
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
        data, response, error in
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0)) {

            if let responseData = data {

                let responseString = NSString(data: responseData, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
                if error != nil {
                    print("Error: \(error)")
                }
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                    print("Response: \(responseString!)")
                }
            }

        }
    }

    task.resume()
```

In terms of handling a failure with your internet connection you should inspect the response send back in the closure and decide what course of action you want to take.

```
    if let httpResponse = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse {
    println("error \(httpResponse.statusCode)")
}
```